# Is there a way to compose together refs with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the use case. I want a user to be able to pass a `ref` to a component. However, I will also have to access that same ref internally.

```
import React, { useRef, forwardRef } from 'react';
import useId from 'hooks/useId';

interface Props extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> {
  readonly label: string;
}

export default forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(({ label, ...props }, ref) => {
  const id = useId();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  // ... more mechanics here
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input {...props} id={id} ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

So here's the problem, I need that `ref` to both be *forwarded* and applied to `inputRef`.

I would think it would be something like this:

```
<input {...props} id={id} ref={compose(ref, inputRef)} />
```

Is this doable in react?

Comment: Can you give some more information about what you are trying to accomplish?  It is possible that there is a better solution that doesn't use `ref` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one ref object into the child, but i don't think that should be a problem. Both you and whoever uses your component should be able to access and use the same ref object.

So you'll just need to check if you were given a ref, and if not create your own. Since hooks need to be called consistently, you'd want to always call useRef, and then just sometimes use the passed in ref instead:

```
export default forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(({ label, ...props }, ref) => {
  const id = useId();
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  ref = ref || inputRef;
  // ... more mechanics here, all referencing `ref`, not `inputRef`
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input {...props} id={id} ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: This is ingenious

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to get the reference to the underlying node, and set both the passed ref and the input ref's current node.

```
export default forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({ label, ...props }, ref) => {
    const id = useId();
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    const setBothRefs = node => {
      ref = node;
      inputRef.current = node;

      console.log(`inputRef`, inputRef, `ref=>`, ref);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
        <input {...props} id={id} ref={setBothRefs} />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: trying to assign `node` to `ref` gives a type error: `TS2322: Type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>'.   Type 'HTMLButtonElement' is not assignable to type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLButtonElement>'.`